# periodic refresh of static data in Structure Streaming and Stateful Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, stateful

I am trying to implement 5 min batch monitoring using spark structured streaming where read from kafka and look up on (1 huge and 1 smaller) diff static datasets as part of ETL logic and call rest API to send final results to an external application (out of billions of records from kafka only less than 100 will be out to rest API after ETL).

1. How to achieve refreshing static look ups with out restarting the whole streaming application ? (StreamingQueryListener using StreamingQueryManager.addListener method to have our own logic of refreshing/recreating static df via StreamingQuery.AwaitTermination ? or use persist and unpersis cache ?  or any other better ideas ?)
   Note : Went through below article but not sure if hbase is better option as its an old one.
   https://medium.com/@anchitsharma1994/hbase-lookup-in-spark-streaming-acafe28cb0dc
2. Once a record is enriched with look up information and applied some rules/conditions , we need to start keep track of it to send updates until it completed its lifecycle of an event as per custom logic via rest API. So hoping flatmapwithGroupState implementation helps here to keep track of event state. Please suggest best options here.
3. Managing group state with in HDFS vs using HBase. Please suggest best options from an operationalization and monitoring point of view in production environment where support team has minimal knowledge of Spark. If we use HDFS for state maintenance, how to keep it up with event state tracking in case of rest API fails to send updates to end user/system?

Comment: Can someone help on this one ?

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: @cricket_007, can you help?